# What is a default dialog box message font size?

Tags: android

With `AlertDialog.Builder.setView` I am showing a custom dialog box like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.custom_dialog_title))
        .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.custom_dialog_prompt))
        // ... 
        .create();

alertDialog.show();
```

Let's have the `custom_dialog` just a simple layout like this (*just an example*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="?dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingEnd="?dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        style="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/custom_dialog_checkbox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My `CheckBox` now uses a default text size, because no `android:textSize` is explicitly specified.

The font size of the default `AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage` text is different than the default `CheckBox` font size. What is a correct way to set the size of the `CheckBox` to match the font size of the `setMessage` text?

As you can see in my example, I use system attribute `?dialogPreferredPadding` for dialog box padding. Is there a similar attribute for a dialog message font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find direct way to determinate the system dialog message text size, I have implemented a workaround...

Before `alertDialog.show();` is called, `OnShowListener` is set/added:

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()  {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        float textSize = 0;
        int messageId = getResources().getIdentifier("message", "id", "android");
        if (messageId > 0)
        {
            View view = ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(messageId);
            if (view != null)
                textSize = ((TextView) view).getTextSize();
        }
        CheckBox checkbox = ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            if (textSize > 0)
                checkbox.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int) textSize);
        }
    }
});
```